# Why does the section symbol (§) not read correctly depending on where it was created?

Tags: ruby, vim, command-line, character-encoding

I am trying to make a tool to scrape usernames from Minecraft log files. In these, there are a lot of section symbols because that's what the game uses for color formatting, and I want to remove them and the following character from each line of the file. However, when I try to read the file with Ruby, I can't get the right character. To try to figure this out, I've inspected a bunch of files containing the section sign in different ways. The files are `a.log`, `b.log`, and `c.log`.

- `a.log` was created by `echo`ing `§` into a file
- `b.log` was created by `cat`ing one of my own Minecraft logfiles, and then deleting all the other characters in Vim
- `c.log` was created in Notepad

When I look at them in Notepad, they're all displaying correctly:

`a.log`:
[image: a.log in notepad]
`b.log`:
[image: b.log in notepad]
`c.log`:
[image: c.log in notepad]

It's the same when I look at them all in Vim:

[image: logfiles in vim]

Then, things start to get weird when I open them in Ruby.
Here's the code I used:

```
a = File.open("./a.log")
aa = a.read
puts aa.encoding
puts aa.ord
puts aa

b = File.open("./b.log")
bb = b.read
puts bb.encoding
puts bb.ord
puts bb

c = File.open("./c.log")
cc = c.read
puts cc.encoding
puts cc.ord
puts cc
```

And here is the output:

```
IBM437
239
§
IBM437
167
▒
IBM437
167
▒
```

I thought that maybe this was just Ruby being weird, until I used `cat` to display the contents of each file:

```
$ cat a.log b.log c.log
§
▒
▒
```

This doesn't make any sense, because the encoding was shown to be the same. So I decided to open each file in a hex viewer (HxD):

`a.log`:
[image: a.log in hex viewer]
`b.log`:
[image: b.log in hex viewer]
`c.log`:
[image: c.log in hex viewer]

What!? All of these contain the same character. The only difference between the one that works and the ones that don't is `EF BB BF C2` in `a.log`! Why does this make a difference, and how can I fix it so it'll work with Ruby's `gsub`?

(I've tried to do this, using a bunch of things I've found online with `String.force_encoding` and `String.encode`, but haven't gotten anywhere except to start seeing degrees symbols in the output. If you can provide an example that works for all three types of log files I would highly appreciate it.)

**EDIT: I did some more playing around and found it was the `C2` byte that's necessary. UTF-8 uses `0xC2 0xA7`, and UTF-16 uses `0x00A7`. What can I do to make this convert correctly (and why don't Notepad and Vim have any issue displaying it as a section sign?)**

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use (< 2.0)? You might be interested in [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: @spickermann `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i386-mingw32]`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your ruby source file is UTF-8 encoded as well. I've seen the symptoms you describe plenty of times using PHP: my source files were in ISO and accessing xml or other kind of data in UTF-8 - or the other way around.

If for some reason you cannot or don't want to encode your ruby files in UTF-8, then you need to dig the file opening functions to make sure they know they will deal with an UTF-8 source.